# 2-in-1 HDD Enclosure with Fan

Tags: usb, sata, drive-enclosure

I recently purchased Inland 3.5" USB 3.0 Hard Drive Enclosure with Fan. (SKU 410464). I like the $25.00 price, the sturdy full metal built chassi/case and the fact that it has a fan. It's not too bad, but I wish there was a similar product available which had 2 of the following attributes/features:

1. The SATA cables and the board are openly exposed, making them prone to damage, I wish if there was a way to just snap my hard drive in the enclosure, I'm afraid that the cables would be damaged faster if I need to change hdd drives more frequently
2. I wish it had a support for 2.5" drives, but I guess I can easily work around this issue by using a adapter bay to use 2.5 HDD inside 3.5 enclosure.

Can you recommend an enclosure?

Comment: What's your budget like?

Comment: I don't have limit, but don't want to spend unreasonable monies. US $25-$30 seems to be the price for most enclosures I've seen so far.